# How to do this without using Files?

Tags: java

I have the following code :

```
Connection.Response captchaResponse = Jsoup.connect(CAPTCHA_URL)
                .timeout(3000)
                .cookies(cookies)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                .method(Method.GET)
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .execute();

        cookies.putAll(captchaResponse.cookies());


        // writing captcha image to file
        FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(new File(CAPTCHA_FILENAME));
        fileWriter.write(captchaResponse.bodyAsBytes());
        fileWriter.close();

        showImage(CAPTCHA_FILENAME,"captcha");
```

`showImage` function:

```
public void showImage(String filename,String title) throws IOException
{
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File(filename)));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
    imageLabel.setIcon(icon);
    frame.add(imageLabel);
    frame.setSize(100,100);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I have a captcha which needs to be displayed. To do this I am storing the captcha in a file and reading the file each time. Is there any way in which I can do this without involving files ?

Comment: what is this `showImage()`?

Comment: function to display captcha in a window (JFrame).

Comment: I don't quite get the question. You can store your captcha in a database, for example. Or in memory. It is a little bit unclear WHY you want to avoid files.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz, I need the captcha only once, so why store it in files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `FileOutputStream` to store the captcha. Then:

```
ByteArrayInputStream imageInput=new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

to transform your `ByteArrayOutputStream` into an `ByteArrayInputStream`to be used in `showImage` with this code:

```
ImageIO.read(imageInput);
```